# How to find the frequency of words in book titles that I have scraped from a website in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am very new to R and webscraping. For practice I am scraping book titles from a website and working out some basic stats using the titles. So far I have managed to scrape the book titles, add them to a table, and find the mean length of the books.
I now want to find the most commonly used word in the book titles, it is probably 'the', but I want to prove this using R. At the moment my program is only looking at the full book title, I need to split the words into their own individual identities so I can count the quantity of different words. However, I am not sure how to do this.

Code:

```
url <- 'http://books.toscrape.com/index.html'

bookNames <- read_html(allUrls) %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " "), concat( " ", "product_pod", " " ))]//a') %>%
  html_text
view(bookNames)

values<-lapply(bookNames,nchar)
mean(unlist(values))

bookNames<-tolower(bookNames)
sort(table(bookNames), decreasing=T)[1:2]
```

I think splitting every word into a new list would solve my problem, yet I am not sure how to do this.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Above is the table of books I have been able to produce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the book titles with :

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'http://books.toscrape.com/index.html'
url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('h3 a') %>%
  html_attr('title') -> titles

titles
# [1] "A Light in the Attic"
# [2] "Tipping the Velvet" 
# [3] "Soumission"      
# [4] "Sharp Objects"   
# [5] "Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind"
# [6] "The Requiem Red"
# [7] "The Dirty Little Secrets of Getting Your Dream Job"
#....
```

To get the most common words in the title then you can split the string on whitespace and use `table` to count the frequency.

```
head(sort(table(tolower(unlist(strsplit(titles, '\\s+')))), decreasing = TRUE))

# the   a  of #1) and for 
# 14   3   3   2   2   2
```

Comment: Is there a way to find out the most used non-stopword. So ignore all of the stopwords and output the most frequent word after that?

Comment: That should have been asked as a new question but you can use `tm::stopwords()` to get stopwords `all_words <- tolower(unlist(strsplit(titles, '\\s+')))` and then `head(sort(table(all_words[!all_words %in% tm::stopwords()]), decreasing = TRUE))`